# How to tell someone to do (something) B while they have not started doing (something) A?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, structure

Since my friend has not watched movie A yet, I want to tell him that watching movie B in the meantime would be a good idea. So, would it would probably be something like:

> Watch movie B until you have not decided to watch movie A.

I am just looking the best way to say this.

Comment: I am a little confused. Does it matter what order the movies should be seen in? Should movie B be seen first? Is your friend more likely to want to watch movie A if he watches movie B first?

Comment: If he hasn't watched movie A yet, then telling him to watch movie B until he ***hasn't*** watched movie A would result in him not watching movie B ***at all*** because the condition to stop watching movie B would be immediately met. But saying the opposite (to watch movie B until he ***has*** watched movie A) would also not make sense. If he's watching movie B, he can never watch movie A in the first place, resulting in him watching movie B for the rest of his life. So, neither scenario—to watch movie B until movie A is or isn't watched—is meaningful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. @JasonBassford you are absolutely right; this is exactly what I have in mind, and therefore, I am wondering what the best sentence in this case would be.

Comment: What is exactly what you have in mind? ;) I'm still not sure what you're trying to say. Is it just *watch movie B before you watch movie A* as in an answer here—or is it something else?

Comment: @JasonBassford lol.. well... It was a long shot. Okay I think I'm not being able to communicate properly, which obviously means that my English still requires a lot of work. I'll try to further clarify my question. It's not the order that I'm focusing on; it's more like a suggestion, like "you may watch movie B in the meantime (until you decide to watch movie A)." Let's say I have been telling my friend to watch GoT and there's this video that comprises the best scenes from all seasons, and so, I tell my friend to watch this video in the meantime (until he decides to watch GoT).

Comment: How will the sentence be? especially the part in the brackets? "(until he decides to watch GoT)"

Comment: @Zaeem *You can watch movie B in the meantime* sounds fine to me. But it seems odd to say ***decide*** *to watch movie A*. I can see saying something like *if you like movie B, you'll probably like movie A*. But waiting on a *decision* is very strange.

Comment: @JasonBassford "You can watch movie B in the meantime sounds fine to me." Okay this makes the first part of the sentence. Now, to incorporate the second part mentioning what "meantime" here refers to. I mean can you make the full sentence? What comes to my mind is something like, "You can watch movie B-" it's the second part I'm confused about. "-until you've watched/not watched/? movie A" Nothing seems to be fitting here.

Comment: “While you’re thinking about whether you want to watch movie A, you can watch movie B.” - I think this is what you’re getting at?

Comment: @Mixolydian yes, I guess I was trying a literal translation from my language to english (not the words but the sentence structure), but perhaps it's not possible in this case. Your sentence is correct. Can the structure be changed a little? Like 1) While you're not watching movie A, you can watch movie B in the meantime OR 2) You can watch movie B in the meantime while you're not watching movie A.

Comment: @Zaeem i think these are better than the sentence with “until” but still not ideal. The “while” part here is too indefinite. When will “not watching movie A” end? When you do something “in the meantime” there’s an implication that you are waiting for something to change, and in this case it’s not clear what that is. Also (as you might already be aware) these 2 sentences have the same meaning - reversing the clauses doesn’t make a difference - so neither 1 nor 2 is better than the other.

Comment: Got it. Thank you everyone for your help, especially @JasonBassford and @Mixolydian; I really appreciate it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous, and I am not sure 100% that I understood your issue.

---

If it is important to watch the movies in the following order:

1. [movie A]
2. [movie B]

then you can say:

> You should not watch [movie B] **before** you watch [movie A].

E.g.:

> You should not watch **Shrek 2** before you watch **Shrek** (the original).